# Inflationary model that predicts both gravitational waves and isocurvature perturbations

Tags: cosmology, gravitational-waves, cosmological-inflation

I 'm searching for inflationary models that predict both gravitational waves and  isocurvature (isothermal) perturbations.

If I understood well, de Sitter inflation predicts only curvature (adiabatic) perturbations but no isocurvature.
So, only inflationary models with two or more scalar fields predict isocurvature  (isothermal) perturbations. The question is, do these models also predict gravitational waves;

I have found for example that **Hybrid inflation** satisfies the second condition: it predicts isocurvature perturbations. But, does it also produce gravitational waves?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.helsinki.fi/~hkurkisu/CosPer.pdf and http://www.helsinki.fi/~hkurkisu/CosPer2.pdf.